# How do you block a user from updating a particular field while allowing a flow to do so?

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, update, status

I need to allow a flow to update a record status to a particular stage, while users are prevented from doing so.

My problem is that if I set a validation rule to prevent users to update a record manually to *Rupture* using the example below, the flow will return an error as well since its interview is launched by a user.

[image]

**How would you go about managing both without throwing an error?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to make sure no users have edit permission for the field then ensure that the [flow runs in system mode](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_system_mode.htm&release=224&type=5). That way no user can directly update the field, but a flow can.

If you still want users to change the status, in specific ways, provide a screen flow (running in system mode) that allows this in a restricted manner to just those statuses you want and set it up as a quick action.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this in the Flow itself. The Flow can check if the value has been changed, and if so, [report an error](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_custom_error.htm&type=5), otherwise set the new desired value. No validation rule necessary.